# Oracle forms10g shows blank page

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I Installed Oracle forms 10g on windows7 and created a sample form . Then I start up OC4J and run the form.

What I get is a blank screen. The URL is http://user-pc:8889/forms/frmservlet
Notice that the form name is not part of the URL.

thnks

Comment: Did you try more than one browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there could be a number of reasons why the blank screen is shown and trying to identify the problem and correct it can be difficult if not impossible without accessing your PC!

My advice is to look at similar problems on the Forms Forum on Oracle Technology Network which can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/forms).

The first search results I found reporting a similar problem can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/forms).

Good luck.